# sql query list number of employees a manager manages

Tags: mysql

I'm doing a small assignment for a database class of mine.
I need to write an sql query to list the last names of all employee managers followed by the number of employees they manage.
This is what the command for inserting an employee into a table looks like:

```
INSERT INTO Employee (Emp_No, Emp_Fname, Emp_Lname, Emp_Status,
Emp_Salary, Emp_Comm, Emp_HireDate, Emp_Mgr_Emp_No, Job_Title, Dept_No)
VALUES (7566, 'Mary', 'Jones', 'active', 2975, NULL, '02-APR-92', 7839,'Manager', 20);
```

This is what I currently have for a query:

```
SELECT emp_lname, COUNT(emp_no) "No_of_Employees"
FROM Employee
WHERE job_title = ('Manager', 'President')
    AND emp_mgr_emp_no IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY emp_lname
```

Which gives something like this:

```
EMP_LNAME             No_of_Employees
Blake                 1
Clark                 1
Jones                 1
```

How would I modify it to list the number of employees for each manager (Including the President, who manages the 3 managers).

Answer (score 0):

Use nested queries to get a list of Employees managed by that particular employee, and count the number of records.

```
SELECT emp_lname, sum(select count(emp_no) FROM Employee B WHERE B.Emp_Mgr_Emp_No = A.emp_no) AS 'Count' FROM Employee A
```

Something like this should work

Comment: Works fine for me. Paste in your CREATE statements and INSERT statements here if you want me to verify, but it should work